# What can be said about a set that is not closed?

Tags: general-topology

Specifically, does a set $A$ that is not closed guarantee that some limit point $x$ of $A$ exist such that $x$ is not contained in $A$?

Comment: yes a set is closed iff it contains all of its limit points

Comment: What s your definition of closed set? Now prepend it with a $\neg$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a topological space $X$, a set $A$ is closed if $X - A$ is open. Furthermore $A$ is closed in $X$, if and only if $A$ contains all of its limit points.

So if there exists a limit point $x$ of $A$, such that $x \not\in A$, then $A$ is not closed and $A$ is not closed if there exists a limit point $x$ of $A$ such that $x \not\in A$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right . for example in usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$,the set $(0,1]$ is not closed because it has $0$ as a limit point which is not in $(0,1]$ and also it is not open .

Hence if set is not closed , we can't say it is open , as in above example it is neither open nor close .